# EOM Double Pendulum with Mass of Rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, oscillators

All the equation's of motion for a double pendulum do not include the masses of both rods. Is there an EOM for a double pendulum that takes into account the masses of the rods (not just the bobs)? Or, how would I incorporate the mass of the rods into the potential and kinetic energy of the system (for the Lagrangian)? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "EOM" you mean "equations of motion".  Editing the question to spell that out wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Model each section of the system as a pair of points with a center of mass and an angle, with moment of inertia and mass.  Define the position of the pivots with respect to the center of mass, as functions of the position of the center of mass and the angle.